# Isometries of a general metric

Tags: differential-geometry, metric-spaces, lie-groups, general-relativity

For a general (pseudo-)Riemannian manifold, i.e. in which the interval $ds$ can be written

$ds^2 = g_{ab}\,dx^a \,dx^b$,

is there a general prescription for finding the group of isometries- by which I mean transformations of the elements $x^a$ such that the metric is preserved (like the Poincare group for Minkowski spacetime)?

Comment: I edited your question to display formulas using [LaTeX](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference). You should implement it in your questions.

Comment: I don't know any such general prescription, even though the conformal subgroup is $\{e^f:f \quad\text{is a positive smooth map}\}$. Furthermore, the isometries of the sphere are the rotations and the isometries of $R^n$ are the rotations and translations.

Comment: There is nothing like this even in Riemannian setting, even for surfaces. You have to get very lucky to find some isometries and then get very lucky to figure out how to show that there are no other isometries.

Comment: So such transformations simply do not exist at all for the majority of metrics?

Comment: Alex: Yes, for "most" metrics, there are no self-isometries except for the identity map.